# PhoneGap Build Android creates floating bubble with 3 dots

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I created an Android app with Phonegap Build and it created a floating bubble with 3 dots in it. When I test my app on my computer it does not create these three dots, only when I run it on my Galaxy S6. Below is a picture:

[image]

Comment: X-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/1kPAHbv7OYw

Comment: Tried that still get bubbles...

Comment: Changing min sdk to 10

Comment: That is not me. I asked about emulator. Please answer on google.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 not using an emulator and also answered on google group

Answer (score 1):

Okay Mike,
I suspected this was addition or replacement for the defunct [Menu Button].

Recently, I did some [demo Apps on Phonegap Events](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Events-test). Among the apps, was the demo for [events: for Physical Buttons (backbutton, menubutton, searchbutton)](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-PhysicalButton-test), which includes [NOTES for changes](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-PhysicalButton-test/blob/master/NOTES.md) in those buttons. The big news was *the Menu button is dead.*

If you Google: [samsung 3 dots galaxy s6](https://www.google.com/search?q=samsung%203%20dots%20galaxy%20s6), the [first link from an Android forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/513901-what-little-circle-three-dots-inside.html) confirms that circle with 3 dots is specific to your *Samsung Galaxy S6*. If you read the thread, it says there is no way to get rid of it. (but I'm not so certain).

In any case, this is NOT a Phonegap or Cordova issue. If anything, it is specific to your phone. Welcome to the Android World!
Best of Luck,
Jesse

Comment: 3 dots on a bar show up on other phones, this is not the answer.

Comment: @Mike, I've responded on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/1kPAHbv7OYw) so we can get more help on this. There are more professionals on that forum. TIA Jesse

Answer (score 1):

Here's the definitive answer, you need to tweak your config.xml:

- If you set either minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion to 11 or higher,
  the system will not add the legacy overflow button.
- Otherwise, the system will add the legacy overflow button when
  running on Android 3.0 or higher.
- The only exception is that if you set minSdkVersion to 10 or lower,
  set targetSdkVersion to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar,
  the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app
  on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.

From: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html