# Phonegap Build testing small circle in corner

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-build

I built the release version of my app and I noticed a small circle that looks like a button in the bottom right corner. Nothing happens when you click it, but I can drag it around the screen. I didn't program it to be there, and it's on every page of my html/javascript app. How can I get rid of it? Here's a picture of it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h01X.jpg

Answer (score 2):

@user3142972,
We just went through this with another person just hours ago. It took days to resolve. This is an issue specific to Samsung. In the end, you must set your *minSDK* and *targetSDK*

The person with the issue posted on two forums. Image are posted in both posts. Here are the two forum posts:

- [3 dot bubble in phonegap app for settings...](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/1kPAHbv7OYw) Google Groups
- [PhoneGap Build Android crates floating bubble with 3 dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900356/phonegap-build-android-crates-floating-bubble-with-3-dots) Stackoverflow

Here are the references you need:

- [Phonegap CLI](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/config_ref_pgb_config.md.html) - EDGE
- [Phonegap Build](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/configuring_preferences.md.html#Preferences)

Lastly, can you please list the phones are test and this oddity occurred. We will document this for other developers to avoid.

**Added Aug 20, 2015**

Here is the "official" blog post related to this issue:

*Say Goodbye to the Menu Button*
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

**Added Oct 6, 2015**

This is issue is likely to hit more developers before the cause dies away. This FAQ entry will help you as more details are added.
*Samsung Soft Menu Button Annoyance*
https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/annoyances/SamsungMenuButton.md

Jesse